# Direct sum isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Sorry, this may not be a good question here but I have no idea.

> Let $\{A_{i}; i\in I\}$ and $\{B_{i}; i\in I\}$ be two different collection of abelian groups. The index set $I$ is the same in both cases.  Let $\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_{i}\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I}B_{i}.$ Is this true for each $i\in I$ there exists an unique $j\in I$ such that $A_{i}\cong B_{j}$?

Thank you.

Comment: This is actually a good question, so don't worry.

Comment: Even though it's false as stated, for example $$\mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}\oplus\{0\}\cong\mathbb{R}\oplus\{0\}\oplus\mathbb{R}. $$ Maybe you want to be able to let the index be different and add some condition.

Comment: Thank you hjhjhj57, I edit my question.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but as stated the example I provided is still a counterexample.

Comment: Another way to see this is if given an abelian group any *maximal* descomposition in direct summands is unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: As a minimum, you would need to assume each $A_i$ and each $B_i$ to be indecomposable, but I have a feeling that this might not be sufficient.

Comment: @CAA: You should add $A_i,B_i \neq 0$ as assumptions (actually much more, as Tobias Kildetoft said).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't hold in general (for example, we have $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \oplus \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}} $), but under some conditions it does hold: [Krull-Schmidt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem).